# Best way to handle segmented bar and multiple views?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ipad

I have a User Filter section of my iPad app. There is a segmented bar with 5 buttons for 5 types of filters.

Clicking each of the buttons will load up the respective view..

My question is.. would the best way to handle the UI of each filter to have several views in this nib and load/unload accordingly.. or would best practice be to create the information in a scrollable view?

below is the setup..
https://i.stack.imgur.com/hYoXk.png

Thanks in advance...

Comment: Is it a filter of the same type of data?  It almost sounds like you're looking for the functionality of a tab bar controller?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Generally, go with separate views. The Scrollable view is an approximation of what you're trying to achieve (by the looks of things), whereas the separate-views more closely reflect your aims.

Some typical dvantages:

- if you change your UI design, e.g. if one of those filters has to go in a different page, but 4 stay here ... then it's easy to move the whole View without changing the eixsting ones.
- you can put each view in a separate NIB file (if they're different), or loaded from a separate ViewController instance (if they're the same), and you get some of the advantages of Apple's automatica memory management of VC's / NIBs.

Usually, people start with the same view for each filter, using a single VC class (instantiated multiple times, once per tab).

Then, as the app evolves, they find that one tab needs a different layout, so they add another VC class, and only need to update the alloc/init line for that one tab.